# Count the total boolean value of true using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Im using java 8. I have a class `Operator` which has 3 fields.

```
class Operator{
    private String type;
    private boolean updateRequested;
    private boolean deleteRequested;
}
```

I have list of `Operator`. I just want to count the `updatedRequested` and `deleteRequested` based on `type` whose value is ***`true`*** and add into the Map which is `Map<String,Result>`

```
class Result{
    private int deleteReqCount;
    private int updateReqCount;
}
```

Expected result

```
{
    "Cricket":{ deleteReqCount:10, updateReqCount:0},  // count only the value == `true`
    "Football":{ deleteReqCount:2, updateReqCount:10}, // count only the value == `true`
}
```

This question is bit simple and I did using for loops and if condition. But I'm impressed with Stream apis and Collectors framework. I'm a beginner, so tried `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(g -> g.getType()));` but couldn't go further.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation using [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

```
class Operator {
    public String type;
    public boolean updateRequested;
    public boolean deleteRequested;
    Operator(String type, boolean updateRequested, boolean deleteRequested) {
        this.type = type;
        this.updateRequested = updateRequested;
        this.deleteRequested = deleteRequested;
    }
}

class Result {
    public int deleteReqCount;
    public int updateReqCount;
    Result(int deleteReqCount, int updateReqCount) {
        this.deleteReqCount = deleteReqCount;
        this.updateReqCount = updateReqCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Result{" +
                "deleteReqCount=" + deleteReqCount +
                ", updateReqCount=" + updateReqCount +
                '}';
    }
}

Map<String, Result> solve(List<Operator> operatorList) {
    return operatorList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    v -> v.type,
                    v -> new Result(v.deleteRequested ? 1 : 0, v.updateRequested ? 1 : 0),
                    (result, result2) -> {
                        int deleteReqCount = result.deleteReqCount + result2.deleteReqCount;
                        int updateReqCount = result.updateReqCount + result2.updateReqCount;
                        return new Result(deleteReqCount, updateReqCount);
                    }
            ));
}

List<Operator> operatorList = Arrays.asList(
        new Operator("cricket", true, true),
        new Operator("cricket", true, false),
        new Operator("cricket", true, true),
        new Operator("soccer", false, true),
        new Operator("soccer", true, true)
);
System.out.println(solve(operatorList));
```

Output:

```
{soccer=Result{deleteReqCount=2, updateReqCount=1}, cricket=Result{deleteReqCount=2, updateReqCount=3}}
```

Comment: The combiner lambda would be a good candidate to add as a method to the `Result` class, e.g. `Result merge(Result that)` or maybe `add`, and then use a method reference `Result::merge`. Makes it reusable.

Comment: that works like chill. As @Andreas said, i used reusable method which reduces the code.

Answer (score 0):

An update to Sai Kiran's excellent answer:

```
Map<String, Result> solve(List<Operator> operatorList) {
    return operatorList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                v -> v.type,
                v -> new Result(v.deleteRequested ? 1 : 0, v.updateRequested ? 1 : 0),
                (result, result2) -> {
                    result.updateReqCount += result2.updateReqCount;
                    result.deleteReqCount += result2.deleteReqCount;
                    return result;
                }
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per comment by @Andreas,

```
    operators.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Operator::getType,
            v -> new Result(v.isDeleteRequested() ? 1 : 0, v.isUpdateRequested() ? 1 : 0),
            Result::merge
    ));
```

Merge method,

```
  public Result merge(Result result) {
      this.updateReqCount+=result.updateReqCount;
      this.deleteReqCount+=result.deleteReqCount;
      
      return this;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

For the time when you update to Java 12 or higher, the task can be achieved using `Collectors.teeing` :

```
List<Operator> ops = //your operators list

Map<String, Result> myMap =          
    ops.stream()
       .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Operator::getType,
                 Collectors.teeing(
                           Collectors.filtering(Operator::isUpdateRequested,Collectors.counting()),
                           Collectors.filtering(Operator::isDeleteRequested,Collectors.counting()),
                           (updateCount, deleteCount) -> {
                                return new Result(updateCount.intValue(),deleteCount.intValue());
                           }
               )));
```

Comment: Yes, I have heard about this, unfortunately i use java8. Thank yyou so much